# omniauth-facebook, integration testing, rspec, capybara - where to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have done a few very simple integration tests for an app for testing an api. I would like to add integration tests for our facebook login. I'm pretty confused as to how to do this. It would seem like there are two alternatives. One is to try to make a call to facebook and actually login. It is unclear to me if my facebook session in Firefox would be used. Another option might be to mock the facebook call to something else and just set the session value manually.

My current user is set currently via:

#### application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Would either of these techniques be possible? Is one better than the other?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You should first read the [Integration Testing](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) section of the omniauth wiki. Basically the approach uses the [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) gem to mock responses from whatever provider you specify.

I use this approach for mocking twitter. In my config/omniauth.rb I have:

```
if (ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'test' || ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'development')
  module OmniAuthHelpers
    def self.add_twitter_mock(uid, name, nickname)
      OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter,
                               { :provider => 'twitter',
                                 :uid => uid,
                                 :info => { :name => name, :nickname => nickname})
end
```

Then in my step definitions (for cucumber), I have:

```
Given /^I am logged into Twitter as the following user:$/ do |table|
  add_twitter_mock(table.rows_hash[:uid],
                   table.rows_hash[:name],
                   table.rows_hash[:nickname])
end
```

And in my features, e.g.:

```
Scenario: Valid login through Twitter
  Given I am logged into Twitter as the following user:
    | name     | John Doe      |
    | uid      | 12345         |
    | nickname | jdoe          |
  And I am on the homepage
  When I click on "Sign in through Twitter"
  ...
```

In this case the "Sign in through Twitter" link links to '/auth/twitter', which then makes a request to the Twitter API which is mocked. Everything after that just proceeds as you would normally (Then I should see a link to "jdoe", etc.)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't use WebMock.